# Bootstrap carousel taking full display of right side of a browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I am trying to get the **boostrap carousel** taking the full display of the right side of a browser window.

For this, the margins of the carousel should by modified to leave the image in the center of the right side at the max width (5/12 of the page) or max height (height of the browser window) depending on the image aspect ratio.

Here is an example of what I am trying to get:

[image]

Here is a Fiddle with how it is working currently: https://jsfiddle.net/v71c8udo/7/

And here is the current HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">website</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-5" style="margin-right:0px;padding-right:0px; height:100vh;">
      <br>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://culturieuse.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/arearea_by_paul_gauguin-joyfulness-1892.jpg" alt="Chania">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://uploads2.wikiart.org/images/paul-gauguin/road-in-tahiti-1891.jpg" alt="Chania">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.leboismiroir.fr/wp-content/uploads/Pld-Gauguin.jpg" alt="Flower">
          </div>


          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that the carousel's height not permanent. My question is what should be the height of the carousel? The height of the highest slide / image?

Comment: the jsfiddle is not working

Comment: @Mosh Feu: it should be the height of the browser window, so flexible.Maybe something to play with html '100vh'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.carousel, .carousel-inner, .carousel-inner > .item{
  height:100%;
  }

body .carousel-inner > .item > img{
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">website</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-7 col-sm-5" style="margin-right:0px;padding-right:0px; height:100vh;">
      <br>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://culturieuse.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/arearea_by_paul_gauguin-joyfulness-1892.jpg" alt="Chania">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://uploads2.wikiart.org/images/paul-gauguin/road-in-tahiti-1891.jpg" alt="Chania">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.leboismiroir.fr/wp-content/uploads/Pld-Gauguin.jpg" alt="Flower">
          </div>


          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After looking closer to this solution , it gives better results in term of regularity on every screen sizes: margin top and bottom are same size.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something like this:

```
#myCarousel {
  height:100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

You need to adjust the padding according to how far you want the slider to be from the top or sides, and you need to reference the whole outer container for this ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v71c8udo/10/)).

Comment: The only thing is that  the margins from top and bottom dont have exactly the same size and on very large screens the image height is geeting bigger than the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but I don't think it's supported by IE<9

```
.carousel {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: You may want to add: 
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);